# Vaadin 24.3.5 AddComponentColumn (JAVA)

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

in the followind code i try to add two column component but only the second appears

```
 Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>(String.class, false);
 grid.addComponentColumn(value ->{
 return new TextField(value);
 }).setHeader("Name");
 grid.addComponentColumn(value ->{
 return new TextField(value);
 }).setHeader("Surname");
 grid.setItems(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Mickey","John"}));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXIvi.png)

I'd like to understand why the first component is not rendered

Comment: I'm using 24.3.6 and cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce with 24.3.5 either